# Regex to replace one function with another in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm looking for a regex that I can call from a Linux command line that would replace a PHP function such as:

```
my_function($one,$two)
```

with:

```
my_new_function($one)->command()
```

I tried:

```
s/my_function\(\$one,\$two\)/my_new_function\($one\)->command\(\)/g
```

but that doesn't seem to match it. $two is no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to escape parentheses. Try this `'s/my_function(\$one,\$two)/my_new_function(\$one)->command()/g'`.

Comment: nice, you can also use `$` instead of `\$` in all three places in this case.. plus OP might benefit from knowing difference between BRE and ERE such as this resource: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y